# Kafka Streams: Count of rows in store

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to get the count of rows in the store, with store being maintained in the low level processor API's.  I see that the method "approximateNumEntries()" can provide an approximate count of key-value mappings in this store.  Can you please clarify on % of accuracy, meaning if there are 100 rows in the store will we get 95 as the approximate count OR could it get even lower than 50 at times?  Just trying to understand the factors that can influence the count accuracy.

Note: Assume that the stream application consumes a single topic and runs on a single instance.  Stores are being accessed through low level processor API's, not sure if there are any caching applied by default.  The commit frequency remains default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the store. If you are using default `RocksDB` store, the method internally returns `"rocksdb.estimate-num-keys"` from RocksDB (cf. https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksDB-FAQ) -- not sure what the error bounds are.

For in-memory stores, the count is actually exact in the current implementation (current release 1.1).